# How to merge two LinkedHashMaps[Int, ListBuffer[Int]] in Scala?

Tags: scala, list, dictionary, linkedhashmap

I found this method:

```
def merge[K, V](maps: Seq[Map[K, V]])(f: (K, V, V) => V): Map[K, V] = {
      maps.foldLeft(Map.empty[K, V]) { case (merged, m) =>
        m.foldLeft(merged) { case (acc, (k, v)) =>
          acc.get(k) match {
            case Some(existing) => acc.updated(k, f(k, existing, v))
            case None => acc.updated(k, v)
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

but it gives me a type mismatch error if i use it like this:

```
val mergeMsg = (map1: LinkedHashMap[Int, ListBuffer[Int]], map2: LinkedHashMap[Int, ListBuffer[Int]]) =>
    {
      val ms=Seq(map1, map2)
      merge(ms.map(_.mapValues(List(_)))){(_, v1, v2) => v1 ++ v2}
    }
```

The error says:
"Type mismatch, expected: mutable.Seq[Mutable.Map[NotInferedK, NotInferedV]], actual: mutable.Seq[Map[Int, List[ListBuffer[Int]]]]"

How can i solve this? I know it's something simple, but i'm new to scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing in to `merge` a sequence of mutable LinkedHashMaps. The function requires a sequence of immutable Maps.

You need to convert your LinkedHashMaps to the correct type first. The simplest way to do this is probably to call `.toMap` before you perform the `mapValues`.

```
merge(ms.map(_.toMap.mapValues(List(_)))){(_, v1, v2) => v1 ++ v2}
```

**Update**

Alternatively the method signature for Merge can be change to explicitly use `scala.collection.Map`. It will, by default, use `scala.collection.immutable.Map`.

```
def merge[K, V](maps: Seq[scala.collection.Map[K, V]])(f: (K, V, V) => V): scala.collection.Map[K, V]
```

Comment: `LinkedHashMap` extends `scala.collection.mutable.Map` which extends `scala.collection.Map`, doesn't it?

Comment: True, but I believe your method signature `...Seq[Map[K, V]]...` will default to using `scala.collection.immutable.Map` (unless you have specifically imported `scala.collection.Map`). You can make this explicit in the signature of merge using something like `def merge[K, V](maps: Seq[scala.collection.Map[K, V]])(f: (K, V, V) => V): scala.collection.Map[K, V]` - which should mean that your original code compiles.

Comment: Thank you, it solved the mismatch, but now it cannot resolve the ++ symbol.

Comment: Please could you post your `merge` method signature and your `mergeMsg` function?

Comment: Now i have `def merge[K, V](maps: Seq[scala.collection.Map[K, V]])(f: (K, V, V) => V): scala.collection.Map[K, V]`. The `mergeMsg` function is not changed.

Comment: The `mergeMsg` function should be fine if `merge` has that method signature. This is working for me: 

`val mergeMsg = (map1: mutable.LinkedHashMap[Int, ListBuffer[Int]], map2: mutable.LinkedHashMap[Int, ListBuffer[Int]]) => {
    val ms = Seq(map1, map2)
    merge(ms.map(_.mapValues(List(_)))) { (_, v1, v2) => v1 ++ v2 }
  }`. Check the parentheses are in the correct place...

Comment: I don't know, parentheses are ok..

I really appreciate your help btw, thank you.

Comment: I'm on this again. The `merge` method merges my LinkedHashMaps into a Map, and i don't want that, I need another LinkedHashMap. What should i change of it?

Answer (score 0):

```
val mergeMsg = (map1: LinkedHashMap[Int, ListBuffer[Int]], 
                map2: LinkedHashMap[Int, ListBuffer[Int]]) => {
      val ms = Seq (map1.toMap, map2.toMap)
      merge (ms) ((_, lb1, lb2) => (lb1 ++ lb2))
 }
```

So the Type needs just to be converted to Map. 
The k is not used for the process of updating, so we use _ instead. 
The lbs are for ListBuffers.